# matplotlib - save plot lines without background and borders and transparency 8 bits alpha channel issue

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, png

I am struggling to save the plot from matplotlib without background and borders.
In particular I would like to export in two formats:

- svg, with only the plot lines (no background, no axis, no frames, no borders)
- png, with transparent background and the bounding box fitting exactly the plot.

To be more precise, I give an example.

```
i = 1000
j = 1024
periods = 6
x = np.array([np.linspace(0, (2 * (periods) * np.pi), i)]).T
x = np.repeat(x, j, axis=1)
n = (1 * (np.random.normal(size=(j))) *
     np.random.uniform(low=1, high=1, size=j))[:, np.newaxis]
n = np.repeat(n, i, axis=1).T
y = np.sin(x) * (np.sin(n)+4) + 0.5 * n**2
xout = np.array([np.linspace(0, 2 * (2 * (periods) * np.pi), 2 * i)]).T
xout = np.repeat(xout, j, axis=1)
yout = np.concatenate((y, y[::-1]))
f1 = plt.figure("GOOD1")
plt.axis('off')
plt.plot(x, y, 'b', alpha=(0.015625))
plt.savefig("GOOD1.svg", bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True)
plt.savefig("GOOD1.png", bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True)
```

This looks similar to what I would like to export but still has a small space on the right in both the png and svg images; the svg has also a background.

The second question is about the alpha channel.
I understood it is limited to 8 bits and hence decreasing the alpha value a bit much more (as to 0.005) will make the plot disappear.
Referring to the previous code, is there a way to plot even more lines with an increased transparency without losing the plot at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how to answer the second part of your question. I believe this code takes care of the border and background issues, though.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i = 1000
j = 1024
periods = 6
x = np.array([np.linspace(0, (2 * (periods) * np.pi), i)]).T
x = np.repeat(x, j, axis=1)
n = (1 * (np.random.normal(size=(j))) *
     np.random.uniform(low=1, high=1, size=j))[:, np.newaxis]
n = np.repeat(n, i, axis=1).T
y = np.sin(x) * (np.sin(n)+4) + 0.5 * n**2
xout = np.array([np.linspace(0, 2 * (2 * (periods) * np.pi), 2 * i)]).T
xout = np.repeat(xout, j, axis=1)
yout = np.concatenate((y, y[::-1]))

f1 = plt.figure("GOOD1")
ax = f1.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.plot(x, y, 'b', alpha=(0.015625))
ax.set_xlim((x.min(), x.max()))
ax.set_ylim((y.min(), y.max()))
f1.patch.set_alpha(0.)
ax.patch.set_alpha(0.)
f1.savefig("GOOD1.svg", bbox_inches=0, transparent=True)
f1.savefig("GOOD1.png", bbox_inches=0, transparent=True)
```

Comment: It works well. Can you explain briefly the added functions?

Comment: The `ax.set_position` function sets the position of the axes in _figure_ coordinates in the format (left, bottom, width, height), so here we are setting the position of the axes at the bottom left corner of the figure and filling the entire figure. Setting the axes limits ensures that the traces fill the entire axes. Setting the figure and axes patch to alpha of 0 makes the background transparent for both the figure and the axes. Finally, and probably most importantly, setting the bbox_inches to 0 makes the output have no border.